# Apache Spark SQL: How to use GroupBy and Max to filter data

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a given dataset with the following structure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJVbY.png

I need to solve the below problem using SparkSQL: Dataframes

For each postcode find the customer that has had the most number of previous accidents. In the case of a tie, meaning more than one customer have the same highest number of accidents, just return any one of them. For each of these selected customers output the following columns: postcode, customer id, number of previous accidents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have missed to provide data that you have mentioned in image link. I have created my own data set by taking your problem as a reference. You can use below code snippet just for your reference and also can replace `df` data Frame with your data set to add required column such as id etc.

```
      scala> val df  = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load("/user/nikhil/acc.csv")
        df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [postcode: string, customer: string ... 1 more field]

        scala> df.show()
        +--------+--------+---------+
        |postcode|customer|accidents|
        +--------+--------+---------+
        |       1|  Nikhil|        5|
        |       2|     Ram|        4|
        |       1|   Shyam|        3|
        |       3|  pranav|        1|
        |       1|   Suman|        2|
        |       3|    alex|        2|
        |       2|     Raj|        5|
        |       4|   arpit|        3|
        |       1|   darsh|        2|
        |       1|   rahul|        3|
        |       2|   kiran|        4|
        |       3|    baba|        4|
        |       4|    alok|        3|
        |       1|   Nakul|        5|
        +--------+--------+---------+


        scala> df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmptable")

   scala> spark.sql(s"""SELECT postcode,customer, accidents FROM (SELECT postcode,customer, accidents, row_number() over (PARTITION BY postcode ORDER BY accidents desc) as rn  from tmptable) WHERE rn = 1""").show(false)
+--------+--------+---------+                                                   
|postcode|customer|accidents|
+--------+--------+---------+
|3       |baba    |4        |
|1       |Nikhil  |5        |
|4       |arpit   |3        |
|2       |Raj     |5        |
+--------+--------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result with the following code in python:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row, Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import *

l = [(1, '682308', 25), (1, '682308', 23), (2, '682309', 23), (1, '682309', 27), (2, '682309', 22)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
people = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(c_id=int(x[0]), postcode=x[1], accident=int(x[2])))
schemaPeople = sqlContext.createDataFrame(people)
result = schemaPeople.groupby("postcode", "c_id").agg(F.max("accident").alias("accident"))
new_result = result.withColumn("row_num", F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("postcode").orderBy(F.desc("accident")))).filter("row_num==1")
new_result.show()
```